# How do I add a new line in a desktop notification in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

This is the project

```
echo $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
echo $notificationTitle = "Aa1234567890"
echo [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] > $null
echo $template = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::GetTemplateContent([Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastTemplateType]::ToastText01)
echo $toastXml = [xml] $template.GetXml()
echo $toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text").AppendChild($toastXml.CreateTextNode($notificationTitle)) > $null
echo $xml = New-Object Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument
echo $xml.LoadXml($toastXml.OuterXml)
echo $toast = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification]::new($xml)
echo $toast.Tag = "Test1"
echo $toast.Group = "Test2"
echo $toast.ExpirationTime = [DateTimeOffset]::Now.AddSeconds(5)
echo $notifier = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier("A7  WIFI  (password saved in clipboard)")
echo $notifier.Show($toast);
```

[Currently, the notification appears like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF8wE.png)

[I want it to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y91f7.png)

**I want to add a new line in the notification is there a way, note: I don't want to change the code I just want to know how to add a new line**

Comment: Guess what, you'll have to change the code. This isn't just "adding a new line", this is adding a new piece of text to the notification, and the "(password saved in clipboard)" thing should not be part of the application id. At the very least it looks like you'll want [`ToastText02`](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toasttemplatetype) as the template.

Comment: You can use a carriage return :CreateToastNotifier("A7  WIFI  `r (password saved in clipboard)")

Comment: or `n  for a new line

Comment: @Christophe [I want it to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y91f7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Jeroen Mostert said, you have to use the template ToastText02, you will be able to use `<text id="1">$Title</text>` for the title and `<text id="2">$Text</text>` for the text in your xml

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$notificationTitle = "Aa1234567890"
$notificationText = "The password has been copied to the clipboard"
$AppID = "A7  WIFI"

[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] > $null
$template = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::GetTemplateContent([Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastTemplateType]::ToastText02)
$toastXml = [xml] $template.GetXml()
($toastXml.toast.visual.binding.text|where {$_.id -eq "1"}).AppendChild($toastXml.CreateTextNode($notificationTitle)) > $null
($toastXml.toast.visual.binding.text|where {$_.id -eq "2"}).AppendChild($toastXml.CreateTextNode($notificationText)) > $null

$xml = New-Object Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument
$xml.LoadXml($toastXml.OuterXml)
$toast = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification]::new($xml)
$toast.Tag = "Test1"
$toast.Group = "Test2"
$toast.ExpirationTime = [DateTimeOffset]::Now.AddSeconds(5)
$notifier = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier($AppID)
$notifier.Show($toast)
```